# Colliderect seems to get triggered based on height

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Currently I am trying to make flappy bird in pygame, but I have stumbled upon an issue where if the bird goes lower than the top of the lower pipe, it detects it as a collision. I also used `collidelist` as my pipe objects are stored in a list, to no avail. Heres the collision code:

```
    def collide(self):
        for pipe_rect in pipes:
            if self.rect.colliderect(pipe_rect):
                pipe.set_scroll(0)
                pipe2.set_scroll(0)
                print("You are dead, no big suprise")
                self.death = True
```

Here is all the code too if that helps:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import QUIT
import random
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
GREY = (100, 100, 100)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 20
        self.__y = screen_y / 2
        self.__vel = 16
        self.death = False
    
    def flap(self):
        self.__vel = 16

    def gravity(self):
        self.__y -= self.__vel
        self.__vel -= 2
        if self.__vel > 15:
            self.__vel = 15
        if self.__y > (screen_y - 50):
            self.__y = screen_y - 50

    def draw(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYWINDOW, YELLOW, (self.__x, self.__y, 50, 50))

    def collide(self):
        for pipe_rect in pipes:
            if self.rect.colliderect(pipe_rect):
                pipe.set_scroll(0)
                pipe2.set_scroll(0)
                print("damn you collision")
                self.death = True


class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = 300
        self.__w = 70
        self.__h = 700
        self.__scroll = 7.5       #world scroll

    def get_w(self):
        return self.__w

    def set_scroll(self, x):
        self.__scroll = x

    def move(self):
        self.__x -= self.__scroll

    def draw(self):
        pipes.append(pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYWINDOW, WHITE, (self.__x, self.__y, self.__w, self.__h))) #bottom
        #pipes.append(pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYWINDOW, WHITE, (self.__x, ((self.__y - self.__h) - 250), self.__w, self.__h))) #top 150 is 3x bird height

    def generation(self):
        if self.__x < 0 - self.__w:
            self.__y = random.randint(275, 450)
            self.__x = screen_x + self.__w



pipes = []
pygame.init()
screen_x = 500
screen_y = 700
DISPLAYWINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_x, screen_y))
bird = Bird()
pipe = Pipe(screen_x)
pipe2 = Pipe((screen_x * 1.5) + pipe.get_w())

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and bird.death == False:
      bird.flap()
        
  DISPLAYWINDOW.fill(GREY)
  bird.draw()
  bird.gravity()
  bird.collide()
  pipe.draw()
  pipe2.draw()
  pipe.move()
  pipe2.move()
  pipe.generation()
  pipe2.generation()
  pygame.display.update()
  CLOCK.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `pipes` list is filled with pipes that are never removed. You can easily test this by inserting `print(len(pipe))` into the application loop.
You must create or delete the pipe list in the application loop before adding the new pipes:

```py
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and bird.death == False:
      bird.flap()

  # clear screen
  DISPLAYWINDOW.fill(GREY)

  # clear pipes
  pipes.clear()
  # draw pipes and add new pipes to list
  pipe.draw()
  pipe2.draw()
  print(len(pipes))

  # draw bird and collision detection
  bird.draw()
  bird.collide()

  # move objects
  bird.gravity()
  pipe.move()
  pipe2.move()

  # generate new objects
  pipe.generation()
  pipe2.generation()

  pygame.display.update()
  CLOCK.tick(30)
```